# How can I search the content of a pdf file in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have given some journal paper in pdf format. I want to find out the title and Author List of the papers. How can I do that in shell scripts ?

Comment: With considerable problems. PDF files are not designed nor meant to be examined this way. Only if you're lucky and both title and author list are explicitly set in the metadata. (So look for a tool to examine PDF metadata.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this works for your journal, it works on some pdf files:

```
strings "myjournal.pdf" | egrep "/Author|/Title" | tr '/' '\n' | egrep "Author|Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project where we had to do search's in the content of a pdf file. The process that we decided to use is the following one:

First we would convert the pdf file to an image with the following command:

```
convert -density 500 "pdf_path.pdf" -depth 8 "image_output.png"
```

And after the file has been created, we use the command below to create a txt file with the pdf's content.

```
tesseract "image_output.png" "out_put_txt_file_name" -l por
```

You are probably going to have to change the `-l por` argument, because we use to do this for text's in portuguese.